# What is the difference between basic and standard public IPs in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-networking, public

Whenever I create a VM, it is taking directly from "Public IP Addresses - Basic" quota,when it will use standard?
And where to set that?

And what is the difference between them?

[image: ips]

Comment: [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question shows you did some **research**, found and **read the vendor documentation**. You're not expected to solve everything yourself, but then at least you can [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that we can help you answer.

Answer (score 6):

For the differences see the  SKU section from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/public-ip-addresses and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/virtual-network-public-ip-address

> All public IP addresses created before the introduction of SKUs are Basic SKU public IP addresses.
> You cannot change the SKU after the public IP address is created. A standalone virtual machine, virtual machines within an availability set, or virtual machine scale sets can use **`Basic`** or **`Standard`** SKUs. Mixing SKUs between virtual machines within availability sets or scale sets or standalone VMs is not allowed.
> **Basic SKU**: If you are creating a public IP address in a region that supports availability zones, the Availability zone setting is set to None by default. Basic Public IPs do not support Availability zones.
> **Standard SKU**: A Standard SKU public IP can be associated to a virtual machine or a load balancer front end. If you're creating a public IP address in a region that supports availability zones, the Availability zone setting is set to Zone-redundant by default. For more information about availability zones, see the Availability zone setting.
> The standard SKU is required if you associate the address to a Standard load balancer. To learn more about standard load balancers, see Azure load balancer standard SKU. When you assign a standard SKU public IP address to a virtual machine's network interface, you must explicitly allow the intended traffic with a network security group. Communication with the resource fails until you create and associate a network security group and explicitly allow the desired traffic.

[image]

Comment: This may be answer to my second part of question, which I already referred this document but posted here as I didn't find the official document much clear. But my main question is not answered yet. Can you please read the first paragraph of my content and answer that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Since this question was posted, Microsoft has **deprecated the Basic SKU for public IPs**.

You now *are* able to upgrade from Basic to Standard IPs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/public-ip-basic-upgrade-guidance

And existing customers are being notified to upgrade before September 30, 2025: e.g. see this [Azure Customer Update Notification Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMAjS.png)

(I don't see a way to adjust the default allocation — the first part of your question — though I suspect default Basic SKU allocations will soon stop.)